# Firebase Application Indexing applicable to my product

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-indexing

I have call recording application which simply record calls and manage those recording. That's all.

Is application indexing applicable to my product as deep link means the application handles the url but what should I handle in my application ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Personal Content Indexing is what you're looking for:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/personal-content

You could create an object to represent a recording, and have metadata associated with it. That could then be searched by your users.